# CodeSandBox: How to access terminal in angular project

Tags: angular, codesandbox, stackblitz

I want to execute some **ng commands** in codeSandBox in an angular project. But I couldn't see any terminal option, whereas I can see terminal when I work on some Node.JS project.
Can anyone please help me to access terminal?
Here is my [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/starter-kit-fqsjc9). Please let me know if I am missing some configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i found so far codesandbox doesn't support Angular CLI out of the box, as they stated in one issue on codesandbox github repository - [here](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/1324#:%7E:text=We%20do%20not%20support%20those%20commands%20for%20now%20so%20you%20do%20have%20to%20create%20the%20files%20manually%20%3A/)

I also found a sandbox project that implements Angular CLI which you can fork and use so on. [Link to codesandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-template-with-terminal-lfs2k)

Good luck